# XML error "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed on Arquillian test with Websphere

Tags: websphere-8, jboss-arquillian, ibm-was

I'm new to Arquillian and trying to get my first test running. I've built the remote Websphere remote container adapter.

This error I understand is usually caused by blanks prior to the xml line but I can't find any leading blanks in the Arquillian.xml. Has anyone had success with the Websphere remote container adapter? It's still early days since its release.

I've followed the example in http://jaxenter.com/integration-tests-with-arquillian-35990-2.html

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<arquillian xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/arquillian-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/arquillian-1.0 http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian-1.0.xsd">

    <engine>
        <property name="deploymentExportPath">target/</property>
    </engine>

    <container qualifier="websphere" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="remoteServerAddress">localhost</property>
            <property name="remoteServerSoapPort">8880</property>
            <property name="securityEnabled">false</property>
            <property name="username">admin</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>
</arquillian>


or the pom.xml


    import mypackage.Client;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class ArquillianTests {

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createArchive() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "testSoapClient.jar").addPackage(Client.class.getPackage());


    } 

    @EJB
    private Client client;

    @Test
    public void testSoapWebServiceClient() throws Exception {

        CleansingServicesOutput cleansedOutput = null;

        try {
             cleansedOutput =  client.cleanse("ABC Plumbing", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.print("WS Exception !!!:"+ex.getMessage());
        }

        assertEquals("Company id has changed", cleansedOutput.getCustomerId(), "ABC Plumbing");
    }


When I "run as" junit test in Eclipse I get.


    [Fatal Error] :2:6: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.


    java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:160)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:111)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:97)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:156)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptor.api.DescriptorImportException: Could not import XML from stream
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptor.spi.node.dom.XmlDomNodeImporterImpl.importAsNode(XmlDomNodeImporterImpl.java:75)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptor.spi.node.dom.XmlDomNodeImporter.importAsNode(XmlDomNodeImporter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptor.spi.node.NodeDescriptorImporterBase.fromStream(NodeDescriptorImporterBase.java:70)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptor.spi.DescriptorImporterBase.fromStream(DescriptorImporterBase.java:147)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.config.impl.extension.ConfigurationRegistrar.resolveDescriptor(ConfigurationRegistrar.java:69)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.config.impl.extension.ConfigurationRegistrar.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationRegistrar.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:145)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:116)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.start(ManagerImpl.java:290)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.<init>(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:56)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptor.spi.node.dom.XmlDomNodeImporterImpl.importAsNode(XmlDomNodeImporterImpl.java:65)
    ... 31 more


my pom is :


        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>ArquilianTests</groupId>
      <artifactId>ArquilianTests</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

      <properties>
              <projectUnderTestDir>C:/radws/workspace/sync8/build/dist</projectUnderTestDir>
      </properties>

      <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

        <testResources>
           <testResource>
             <directory>src</directory>
           </testResource>
        </testResources>

         <plugins>
           <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                  <source>1.6</source>
                  <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.17</version>
                <dependencies>
                  <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                    <version>2.17</version>
                  </dependency>
                </dependencies>
             </plugin>
         </plugins>
        </build>

        <dependencies>
           <dependency>
                <groupId>client</groupId>
                <artifactId>sync</artifactId>
                <version>0.1</version>
                <scope>system</scope>
                <systemPath>${projectUnderTestDir}/Sync.jar</systemPath>
           </dependency>  
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.8.2</version>
       <!--      <scope>test</scope>  -->    
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
                 <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-impl-maven</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
       <!--       <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency> -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!--  
            <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                  <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                  <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
                  <type>pom</type>
                  <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency> -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-was-remote-8.5</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Beta1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>  
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.4</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency> 
        </dependencies>

        <dependencyManagement>
          <dependencies>
             <dependency>
                 <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                 <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                 <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
                 <scope>import</scope>
                 <type>pom</type>
             </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0-alpha-1</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
                <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0-alpha-4</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
           </dependencies>
         </dependencyManagement>
    </project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got past this error after moving my arquillian.xml to the root src folder. Looks like it couldn't find the file.

While https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ARQ/Container+configuration says the file is optional somehow this was creating a problem.